# Snowflake - how do i grant read only to ALL Databases for a role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there way to grant a role view/read-only permission to ALL Databases? Both present and future databases? I  read the GRANT FUTURE Command doesnt work for databases, but will be added down the road?

Comment: Short answer is no as access control is granular and there is no supported role that offers READ-ONLY at database level.
Allowed ALL syntax is usually for schemas (top level) - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#syntax
One way to achieve sharing from multiple DBs is via shares; however, it still involves giving multiple grants - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-mutiple-db.html#sharing-data-from-multiple-databases
You can do grant all on objects in a database - e.g. grant select on all tables in database test_db to role test_role;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can do this.](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-grant-select-on-all-future-tables-in-a-schema-and-database-level) Just not all in one command. Fortunately, we can generate the commands we need with the Information schema.

I would think carefully if you really want to grant access to all future tables that could ever be added to a database. Depending on the type of data in the database and who has access to create tables, this could become a security concern.

That being said, the script below might help

```
-- set your role with access to make these changes
use role accountadmin;

-- set context to any database you have create table privlages in, this is only for the temp table.
use schema sandbox_db.public;

-- set the role you want to give access to
set v_role = 'TEST ROLE';

-- list out shares. db's made from share use different permissions
show shares;

-- add databases made from shares into a temp table
create or replace temp table inbound_shares_temp as (
SELECT "database_name" as db_name FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()))
WHERE "kind" = 'INBOUND'
);

-- generate your select on all current and future tables commands
-- copy and paste the results and run
select 'grant usage on database ' || DATABASE_NAME || ' to role $v_role;' as "--commands" from information_schema.databases
where database_name not in (select db_name from inbound_shares_temp)
union all
select 'grant usage on all schemas in database ' || DATABASE_NAME || ' to role $v_role;' from information_schema.databases
where database_name not in (select db_name from inbound_shares_temp)
union all
select 'grant select on all tables in database ' || DATABASE_NAME || ' to role $v_role;' from information_schema.databases
where database_name not in (select db_name from inbound_shares_temp)
union all
select 'grant usage on future schemas in database ' || DATABASE_NAME || ' to role $v_role;' from information_schema.databases
where database_name not in (select db_name from inbound_shares_temp)
union all
select 'grant select on future tables in database ' || DATABASE_NAME || ' to role $v_role;' from information_schema.databases
where database_name not in (select db_name from inbound_shares_temp);
```